# Angular2: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAsync' of undefined"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

### The Unit Test

```
import {Goal} from '../../providers/goal/goal';
import {GoalSettingsPage} from './goal-settings';

import {Modal, Alert, NavParams, ViewController, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import {provide,ReflectiveInjector,Component} from '@angular/core'
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/common';

import {
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  xit, 
  TestComponentBuilder, 
  ComponentFixture, 
  inject,
  async
} from '@angular/core/testing';


describe('Goal Settings', () => {

    it('should display header title: "Some Title"', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(GoalSettingsPage).then((fixture) => {
            fixture.detectChanges();

            var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

            expect(compiled.innerHTML).toContain('ion-title');               
            expect(compiled.querySelector('span'))        .toHaveText('Cancel');
            expect(compiled.querySelector('ion-title')    .innerText).toBe('DrEvil');

        });
  }));
```

### The Error Message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAsync' of undefined

### The Question

Pascal writes here: http://5thingsangular.github.io/2016/04/11/issue-1.html that `injectAsync` is deprecated, so how do I `createAsync` like the cool dudes do?

**Update:** error disappeared after restart of gulp. Now I get this:

> Error: No provider for TestComponentBuilder!

**Update2:**

Solved by injecting in describe scope instead of it scope:

```
    let tcb;

    //setup
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        TestComponentBuilder
    ]);

    beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], _tcb => { 
        tcb = _tcb
    }));
```

**New error**

> Error: No provider for Compiler!

Answer (score 5):

Importing `TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS` and `TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS` as in:

```
import {
  TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
}  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

.. solved my last error.